# How to run ffmpeg as c program

Tags: c, ffmpeg, video-streaming

I am a student currently work on real-time video transmission, recently I found ffmpeg command line is very powerful in real-time **encoding/decoding**.

But what I want to do is move the c program of the encoding/decoding part (corresponding to ffmpeg command line) into our general big c program.

The problem is, I have already found the corresponding c program file in ffmpeg source folder (but actually I am not sure whether it is or not) its in `home/ffmpeg sources/ffmpeg/example/decoding_encoding.c`.

I opened the file but cannot run it in Codeblocks, it gives the error

```
undefined reference to 'av_crc'
```

and a lot of 'undefined reference' error.

1. Does anybody have any idea how to solve this?
2. And any other idea of how to trans **ffmepg** command line to c program?

Comment: That is perfectly doable, just grab the code and check which parts you don't need. The `ffmpeg` executable is very extense, so it will be a very difficult taks. Writing new code based on the `ffmpeg` -> `libav*` libraries should be easier, although it would be even better to try some [gstreamer](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/) solution. Also, your problem is that `ffmpeg` executable links to some of the `libav*` libs, as you can suspect from the undefined reference function name `av_crc`.

Answer (score 0):

One cannot simply take a single file from a project and make it run on its own: it has dependencies.
Looking at the [1st result](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/README.md) of the google query `ffmpeg c` you will find the `ffmpeg`  project git repository, its documentation and even coding examples to achieve what you want.

Comment: I have viewed the website and the file on it is the same as my ffmpeg file, I still do not know which one is corresponding to the **encoding/decoding** function......